# How to center bootstrap nav bar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a bootstrap navbar, I want to center `home` `page1` `page2` `page3` . I've searched all related questions in stackoverflow but I couldn't find any suiting my purpose, I've used `padding` and it works but when I shrink the browser, the selected items get displayed having inappropriate size. This is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/wr3t003r/

Answer (score 2):

an easy way is to add a `text-center` class to your nav bar. like this:

`<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-center">`

Comment: Thank you , I used it before but it didn't work for me :/

Comment: well i used this in the jsfiddle link that you shared and it worked. doesn't your sign up and login link center on top of each other?

Comment: yes dear , you're right , it works fine  for all items in navbar but when browser is maximize it doesn't work for main menu ( submenus works fine all times )

Answer (score 0):

You just needed a couple of styles to get the behaviour that I think you wanted. It looks like you were going the `display:inline-block` route to center the elements, so I'll just continue along that approach. To your existing styles, add/modify definitions so that these styles are included:

```
.nav.nav-center {
    margin:0;
    float:none;
}

.navbar-inner{
    text-align:center;
}
```

With that, the two options should move to the exact center of your navigation bar. Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/b7whs/67/) to show you what this would look like. I hope this is what you were looking for! If not, let me know and I'll be happy to help further.

Comment: Thank you , I used your code but it didn't work for me , I try many examples but I didn't successful :( , but thanks for your time

Comment: Use the html in the JSFiddle I provided and modify the links to what you need. Then use the CSS as I have outlined. This should work unless you have other CSS overriding the changes.

Comment: I changed my code , it works fine  when browser shrink , but when browser is maximize it showed on right  http://jsfiddle.net/cb6mhpbh/

Comment: I checked all css and I'm sure , issue isn't in css :/

Comment: I got it to center except when browser is small... [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7whs/182/) maybe you can work with this until I get more time.